# Create a Inner Join to create proper output

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get my data to look like the output below. I have a SQL with a Inner Join to
 connect two tables so they will output the data so it looks like the below. I am not sure how to do this could somebody give me a example

This is what the output looks like now

```
First American
2014-03-17 Blackwell Vancouver 115
First American
2014-04-21 Kurth Vancouver 85
Title Source
2014-01-04 Kurth Vancouver 85
Title Source
2014-03-11 Kurth Vancouver 85
Title Source
2014-03-17 Kurth Vancouver 85
```

This is what I would like it to look like

```
First American 

2014-03-17 Blackwell Vancouver 115
2014-04-21 Kurth Vancouver 85

Title Source

2014-01-04 Kurth Vancouver 85
2014-03-11 Kurth Vancouver 85
2014-03-17 Kurth Vancouver 85



$result = $db->query("SELECT customers.name,signings.pid,signings.done,signings.signstart,
signings.lname,signings.ordern,  signings.city,signings.samount,signings.prtamount,
signings.faxamount FROM customers Inner Join signings On signings.custid = customers.custid 
WHERE signings.pid = 6 AND signings.done = 1 GROUP BY customers.name, signings.pid, 
signings.done,signings.signstart");
foreach($result as $key => $income) {

  echo $income['name'];  

  echo '<br>';
  $total = $income['samount'] + $income['prtamount'] + $income['faxamount'];
  echo $income['signstart'] . ' ' .$income['lname']. ' ' .$income['city'] . ' ' .$total;

  echo '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your PHP like this:

```
$current=null;
foreach($result as $key => $income) {
if($current!=$income['name']){
    echo $income['name'];
    $current = $income['name'];  
}

//other stuff
}
```

Hope this solves it!